# How do 使って　and 説明する　interact here?

Tags: grammar

The following excerpt is taken from a conversation with my languagepartner.
For context:

私が Skype のインスタントメッセージ機能で、リアルタイムに日本語の会話をすることはあまりありません。お互いにオンラインで、会話を楽しみたいときは、英語を使うことが多いです。

基本的には italki と同じです。時間があるときにメッセージを読んだり書いたりします。Skype の便利なところは、イラスト、写真、リンク、ファイルなど、いろいろなものを送れるところです。文章を読むだけではわかりにくいことも、イラストや写真、時にはYouTubeの動画なども使って説明することができます。モチベーションを保つためには、楽しみながら学ぶことが大切だと思います。

The sentence in question:
文章を読むだけではわかりにくいことも、イラストや写真、時にはYouTubeの動画なども使って説明することができます。

My attempt at translation:
"Though it is hard to understand at reading essays, while using Youtube videos and the like *when/in times of (???)* Illustrations and photos, you can explain/expose."

Beforehand, has anyone got a better idea for わかりにくい instead of "hard to understand"? At least in my translation, it isn't optimal, but I kind of lacked the creativity to come up with something better.

To the matter at hand: I think 使って and 説明することができます are connected in the way that "while doing X, I can expose/show (Y)." I think in this context "to expose" is more suitable than "to explain", although basically both are very well possible here. Still, especially with the phrase イラストや写真、時には  I have no idea how to integrate the parts inside the 使って phrase so that I can properly attach the 使って phrase to the 説明 phrase. In the 時に phrase, there is a lack of verb isn't there?

Also in 文章を読むだけではわかりにくいことも, I wonder wether ことも connects to できます? I guess not, but I can't rule it out yet since my understanding of the full sentence is less than optimal. I think こと simply references back to SKYPE in the usecase of 文章を読む: "Only at reading essays, it (=usecase "read essay with Skype") is hard to understand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's 時には that mainly threw you off.

- Aも説明することができます。
  I can explain also/even A. (Note that も is replacing を)
- 文章を読むだけではわかりにくいこと
  **things** which are hard to understand just by reading text (um, why "though"?)
- [時には](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)
  **sometimes** (This 時には is not "when" because it doesn't follow a verb or `noun + の`)

  > 私は時にはコーヒーも飲みます。 I sometimes drink coffee, too.
- イラストや写真、時にはYouTubeの動画など
  things such as illustrations, photographs or **sometimes** YouTube videos
- ～も使って
  also using ～; also with the aid of ～

My attempt is as follows:

> 文章を読むだけではわかりにくいことも、イラストや写真、時にはYouTubeの動画なども使って説明することができます。
>   Things which are hard to understand just by reading text can be explained with the aid of illustration, photographs or sometimes YouTube videos.